# Pangaea, supercontinent formation and fragmentation

Tags: plate-tectonics, earth-history

Is there a widely accepted model for the [supercontinent cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinent#Supercontinent_cycles) ?

From the novice point of view, it is not obvious why the continents would be fragmented all over the earth as now, but 300 millions years ago it was the opposite, they were assembled into one single supercontinent : the [Pangaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea).

Also this [list of supercontinents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supercontinents) suggests it never stopped oscillating between fragmented and concentrated during earth's history, so that on the long term, the continents don't appear following a random law for their relative position (as the [plate tectonics driving forces model would suggest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics#Driving_forces_of_plate_motion)).

So is there an explanation for that, or is it mainly observational with no trustful model behind this oscillation of the lands concentration, from one extremum to the other ?